# Enqueue operation code interpretation in c language

Tags: c, pointers, queue, malloc

This is Queue ADT and I have a question in the 'Enqueue' part..

```
//Queue ADT Type Defintions
    typedef struct node
        {
        void* dataPtr;
        struct node* next;
        } QUEUE_NODE;
    typedef struct
        {
        QUEUE_NODE* front;
        QUEUE_NODE* rear;
        int count;
        } QUEUE;
//Prototype Declarations
    QUEUE* createQueue (void);
    QUEUE* destroyQueue (QUEUE* queue);
    bool dequeue (QUEUE* queue, void** itemPtr);
    bool enqueue (QUEUE* queue, void* itemPtr);
    bool queueFront (QUEUE* queue, void** itemPtr);
    bool queueRear (QUEUE* queue, void** itemPtr);
    int queueCount (QUEUE* queue);
    bool emptyQueue (QUEUE* queue);
    bool fullQueue (QUEUE* queue); 
//End of Queue ADT Definitions


bool enqueue (QUEUE* queue, void* itemPtr)
{
//Local Definitions
QUEUE_NODE* newPtr;
//Statements
if (!(newPtr =
    (QUEUE_NODE*)malloc(sizeof(QUEUE_NODE))))
    return false;

newPtr->dataPtr = itemPtr;
newPtr->next = NULL;
if (queue->count == 0)
// Inserting into null queue
    queue->front = newPtr;
else
    queue->rear->next = newPtr;

(queue->count)++;
queue->rear = newPtr;
return true;
} // enqueue
```

Here, I wonder what does

```
!(newPtr =
(QUEUE_NODE*)malloc(sizeof(QUEUE_NODE)))
```

this mean...

I know that malloc creates dynamic memory but we haven't assign anything to newPtr yet, and how can we compare with memory pointer?? I assumed that this is the checker whether the queue is full or not.

Thanks a lot..

+) Now I understand the code.... Could somebody answer this, too? In what case does the memory assignment fail?

Comment: It tests if you successfully allocated memory for `newPtr`. Its the same as `newPtr = malloc(sizeof(QUEUE_NODE));` and then `if(newPtr == NULL) {}`

Comment: @AliciaMay - I've answered your initial question and your follow-up question below.  Please select an answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

It is checking if `malloc` failed or not. Not an issue with linked list. To give you a flavour, I am showing you an example of allocating n memory locations which will store `int`.

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
if( p == NULL )
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%s","error");
    exit(1);
}
```

Here in your case it returns false when it can't allocate denoting that enqueue operation has failed.

Also casting the `malloc` is not required. Don't do this - it's bad practice.

Also whatever you allocate `free` it when you are done working with the allocated memory. That saves you from memory leak,

```
free(p);
p=NULL;
```

#### Dissection of the line:-

```
!(newPtr =
(QUEUE_NODE*)malloc(sizeof(QUEUE_NODE)))
```

The value of assignment expression is the assigned value itself. So if this allocation returns `NULL` then `!NULL` will be condition in if block. Which will be true meaning that the malloc has failed and the enqueue operation will not be performed. (NULL is considered to be zero, that `!NULL` is something non-zero and anything nonzero in C is considered to be `true`)

Same code can be written this way:-

```
QUEUE_NODE *newPtr = malloc(sizeof(QUEUE_NODE)));
if(newPtr == NULL ){
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Downvoter please ..mention what's wrong? This answers what is asked by the user?

Answer (score 0):

It is checking to see if the `malloc()` succeeded.  If it returns `NULL` then the statement will evaluate to false, and trigger the `return false`.

Logically speaking, here's a simple breakdown of how it works:

Step 1: The `malloc()` fails to allocate memory and returns NULL, so the expression is now this:

```
if (!(newPtr = NULL))
    return false;
```

Step 2: The `newPtr` is assigned, and its assigned value is used:

```
if (!(NULL))
    return false;
```

Step 3: This is some C basic knowledge that people either love or hate.  In C, anything that evaluates to zero is considered logically `false`, and anything non-zero evaluates to logically `true`.  `NULL` is equivalent to zero, which means it is logically equivalent to `false`:

```
if (!(false))
    return false;
```

Step 4: The `!` (the logical NOT operator) flips the `false` to `true`:

```
if (true)
    return false;
```

Thus through these steps, if `malloc()` returns `NULL` that evaluates to `false`, and the `!` (logical NOT) changes the entire expression to `true`.  This in turn causes the function to return `false`, indicating failure.

EDIT: To answer your additional question: `malloc()` will return NULL if you attempt to allocate too much memory, e.g. more than the system has available and/or more than the system will allow.  Go ahead and try it.  Run a loop that repeatedly allocates memory without freeing it and it will eventually return NULL.